# Return a struct from a body stream

Tags: rust, hyper

Please assist, i have looked at the [hyper doc](https://hyper.rs/guides/server/echo/) and [example](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/tree/master/examples)

Most examples when dealing with hyper `Request<Body>` will either `map(|chunk|{ //do something })` or `and_then(|chunk|{ //do something })` then return the Stream, that works but now i want to try and return the chunk or actual item in the stream. see below

```
pub fn to_struct(body: Body) -> Option<Person> {
    let person = body.and_then(|chunk|{
        let body = std::str::from_utf8(&chunk).unwrap();
        let results: Person = serde_json::from_str(&body).unwrap();
        Ok(results)
    });
    // match person or if let 
    // return Some or None

    // Don't wan't to Body::wrap_stream(person) then return Response<Body>
}
```

`streams do nothing unless polled` now i want to poll the following stream and return the results.`await` might solve the issue i believe but i am using rust Stable. I wish to `poll()` but i will receive a `NotReady`.Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use hyper synchronously, by nature hyper is not made for that and require a layer of abstraction, you should look at this
 [issus](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/123)

```
There is no documentation specifically to that effect. Since
you'd need to block the thread at a certain point in execution
until it is ready, you'd need the work of the event loop to occur
in another thread, and send the results over a channel that you
block on.

Alternatively, you can look at reqwest, which even with the hyper
upgrade (not quite released to crate.io, but super soon), it
still offers a synchronous API besides the new async API.
```

Note: `reqwest` is now released on crate.io